# How to fix possible corrupted files from decrypted drive?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery, bitlocker, file-corruption

I recently gave in my external HDD to Seagate for data recovery and they sent me back a drive with the contents encrypted (Bitlocker). I decrypted the contents but it seems like all the files are corrupted - or at least it looked like it is corrupted. I opened a word document in the text editor and it contains (just posting a segment):

`Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????‚‡\‚‡\         6086882MltCpy2.19 FILL FILLed Sector; ST2000NM001A-2J2101 (SN01) WJC05WBSa Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????„‡\„‡\         6086883MltCpy2.19 FILL FILLed Sector; ST2000NM001A-2J2101 (SN01) WJC05WBSa Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????‰‡\‰‡\         6086884MltCpy2.19 FILL FILLed Sector; ST2000NM001A-2J2101 (SN01) WJC05WBSa Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????`

I inspected an image file in text editor and found similar contents:

`Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery Labs??????????????¯ﬁn„¯ﬁn„      3815694072MltCpy2.19 FILL FILLed Sector; ST2000NM001A-2J2101 (SN01) WJC05WBSa Recovery Labs??????????????Data Recovery`

Would appreciate any tips on how I should proceed.

I tried running `chkdsk` on the drive to fix possible HDD corruption and that did not work.

Comment: Whats meant by `Did not work`.  Did chkdsk give errors ?

Comment: The files come from a data recovery service, they should have you informed that some of them could be damaged beyond repair. It looks like they filled the unrecoverable parts with that strings. They probably did the best they could and there is nothing you can do to fix the files at this point. Let this be a lesson on how important backups are and adjust your backup strategy.

Comment: @RohitGupta chkdsk said it did not find any discrepancies after scanning for 4 hours :/

Comment: @croomie - That sort of info thats nice to have in the original question.  As mashuptwice has said, they would have recovered what they could.  I would expect a report somewhere telling you which files they could recover fully.  But there is nothing else you can do.  In fact, it is too late as the disk has been written to extensively now.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to recover files from an encrypted drive is to use `repair-bde` for example:

`repair-bde C: D: -force -rp 111111-222222-333333-444444-555555-666666-777777-888888`

which will recover from C to D with the recovery key (please adjust accordingly). Regular commands like `chkdsk` won't work. This is how I fixed my issues when I ran into a corrupted and encrypted drive.

I'm not sure though this will work after you decrypted the drive. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't encrypted data, this is a placeholder for data/sectors that could not be read at all. 6086882, 6086883, 6086884 are LBA addresses. It literally says "FILLed Sector".

At the first chance a data recovery lab gets it will try to image / clone a drive. In many pro data recovery tools one can configure what to write in non readable sectors and it seems this lab took the opportunity to advertise. It seems the tool used was called MltCpy2.19 (MultiCopy probably?), I have never heard of it. It may be tool that they developed in-house.

Any half decent data recovery lab should be able to tell you, and should tell you, we recovered data but were unsuccessful in copying x amount of sectors. Professional disk imagers often are able to pinpoint exact files that are probably corrupt due to bad sectors if file system meta data, that allows exact LBA addresses to be tied to individual files, could be recovered too.

I saw similar case at Reddit this week, or is this came case? TBH it sounds like a sloppy lab.

EDIT: Spoke to some colleagues who have seen similar cases. Supposedly all these have in common they were sent to Seagate for data recovery.

[image]